# The binding type(s) 'signalR' are not registered

Tags: node.js, signalr, azure-functions

I had it working a day ago and I'm not sure what's changed, but now when I run `func start`
I get the following errors for my SignalR `negotiate` and `messages` nodejs function. I tried installing function core tools v2 and v3, but issue is still there. I appreciate any help!

[image]

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureSignalRConnectionString": "<endpoint>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7070,
    "CORS": "http://localhost:4200",
    "CORSCredentials": true
  }
}
```

negotiate function

```
module.exports = async function (context, req, connectionInfo) {
  context.res.json(connectionInfo);
};
```

messages function

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  return {
    "target": "newMessage",
    "arguments": [ req.body ]
  };
};
```

Comment: `signalr` and `signalrconnectioninfo` should be included in the ExtensionBundle. When developing locally, make sure you are using the latest version of Azure Functions Core Tools. If this issue still happens, try to create a new project.

Comment: I updated to the latest version and I removed binding reference like so https://pastebin.com/dPEnV87X  I also downloaded fresh zip of sample doc from MS tutorial here and reconfigured it, but it's still not connecting with client. Sample repo: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/signalr-service-quickstart-serverless-chat/tree/master/src/chat/javascript which comes from this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-azure-functions-javascript. It connected a couple days ago, but now all I get in the browser is https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZIh0.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested the nodejs sample provided in [this link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/signalr-service-quickstart-serverless-chat/tree/master/src/chat/javascript) and it worked fine.

The steps are

1.Download the project.

2.Rename `local.settings.sample.json` to `local.settings.json`

3.In `local.settings.json`, paste the connection string into the value of the **AzureSignalRConnectionString** settings.

Based on the error message you provided, please make sure the Service mode of your SignalR Service is **Serverless**. And please check the **CORS** configuration in the `local.settings.json` file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you still encounter 'The binding type(s) 'signalR' are not registered' issue, you can try to delete the **extensionBundle** settings in `host.json` file and run again. It will install the SignalRService extension automatically.

[image]

[image]

In this way, you might need to add **AzureWebJobsStorage** setting in `local.settings.json` file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tony Ju! I got it working by downloading a fresh copy of the repo. I was able to connect to the serverless vue chat app MS provides. (I did this step before, but noticed that my current code was no longer connecting to it so I must of messed up some code somewhere. Anyways a fresh copy worked and I got Angular connected too!